# What is causing this cube to not render?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw, glm-math

When running the program, the camera seems to work fine and I can manipulate the clear colour but the cube itself will not render.

*Here's my code:*

(The camera and renderer objects are both declared in their respective header files along with their methods)

### Main.cpp

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include "Shapes.h"
#include "Renderer.h"
#include "Camera.h"

int main()
{
    Renderer* renderer = new Renderer(800, 800, (const char*)"OpenGL Sample Test", glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    GLFWwindow* window = renderer->getWindow();

    Block* cube = new Block(renderer);
    cube->setColourTint(glm::vec4(0.3f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 1.0f));

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {       
        renderer->updateRender();
        cube->rotate((float)glfwGetTime() * glm::radians(50.0f), glm::vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f));
    }

    delete renderer;

    return 0;
}
```

### Renderer.cpp

```
#include "Renderer.h"
#include "Shapes.h"

Renderer::Renderer(int Window_X, int Window_Y, const char* Window_Title, glm::vec4 ClearColour)
{
    Renderer::renderList = new std::vector<Shape*>;
    Renderer::clearColour = ClearColour;
    Renderer::WINDOW_X = Window_X;
    Renderer::WINDOW_Y = Window_Y;
    Renderer::WINDOW_TITLE = Window_Title;
    
    createWindow();

    std::cout << "Running OpenGL extension checks... ";

    GLenum glewTest = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != glewTest)
    {
        std::cout << "FAILED";
        std::cout << (const char*)glewGetErrorString(glewTest) << std::endl;
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    }

    //OPENGL//
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glViewport(0, 0, Window_X, Window_Y);

    Renderer::shader = new Shader("Vertex.glsl", "Fragment.glsl"); //Create the shaders
    Renderer::camera = new Camera(Window_X, Window_Y, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f));

    Renderer::modelMatrixShaderLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader->ID, "model"); //Grab the name of the uniform of the model matrix
    Renderer::fragmentColourTintLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader->ID, "colourTint");

    glCheckError();
}

void Renderer::createWindow()
{
    //Define OpenGL Version | Create Window
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    std::cout << "Creating GLFW Window... ";

    Renderer::window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_X, WINDOW_Y, WINDOW_TITLE, NULL, NULL);

    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: GLFW WINDOW FAILED TO INSTANTIATE" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

        //Key Callbacks
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
        glfwSetWindowCloseCallback(window, close_callback);
        glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
    }
}

bool Renderer::updateRender()
{
    glClearColor(clearColour.r, clearColour.g, clearColour.b, clearColour.a); //Add background color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); //Clear the color and depth back buffers
    shader->use();  //Bind to the shader program

    for (int i = 0; i < renderList->size(); i++)
    {
        Shape* current = renderList->at(i);
        current->clearMatrix();
    }

    //Refresh the projection matrix
    //projection = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    //projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)WINDOW_X / (float)WINDOW_Y, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    //shader->setMat4("projection", projection);

    glCheckError();

    for (int i = 0; i < renderList->size(); i++) //Update matrix of each renderable object
    {
        Shape* current = renderList->at(i);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrixShaderLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(current->getPosition()));
        glUniform4f(fragmentColourTintLocation, current->getColourTint().r, current->getColourTint().g, current->getColourTint().b, current->getColourTint().a);

        glBindVertexArray(current->getVAO());
        std::cout << "Drawing: " << current << " : " << current->getVAO() << std::endl;
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, current->getIndicesStride(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glCheckError();
    }

    camera->Inputs(window); //Process camera input
    //Camera Matrix updating
    camera->Matrix(45.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f, shader, "camMatrix");

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();

    if (glCheckError() != NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

Renderer::~Renderer()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < renderList->size(); i++)
    {
        Shape* current = renderList->at(i);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, current->getVAOAddress());
        glDeleteBuffers(1, current->getVBOAddress());
        glDeleteBuffers(1, current->getEBOAddress());
        delete current;
    }
    
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    glDeleteProgram(shader->ID);
    delete renderList;
    delete shader;
    delete camera;
    
}

GLFWwindow* Renderer::getWindow()
{
    return window;
}

void Renderer::push_Renderer(Shape* Renderable_Object)
{
    renderList->push_back(Renderable_Object);
}

void Renderer::updateClearColour(glm::vec4 ClearColour)
{
    clearColour = ClearColour;
}
```

### Camera.cpp

```
#include "Camera.h"

Camera::Camera(int width, int height, glm::vec3 position)
{
    Camera::width = width;
    Camera::height = height;
    Position = position;
}

void Camera::Matrix(float FOVdeg, float nearPlane, float farPlane, Shader* shader, const char* uniform)
{
    //Matrix Magic
    glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::mat4(1.0f);

    view = glm::lookAt(Position, Position + Orientation, Up);
    projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(FOVdeg), (float)(width / height), nearPlane, farPlane);
    //std::cout << "XYZ: " << Position.x << " : " << Position.y << " : " << Position.z << std::endl;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader->ID, uniform), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection * view));
}

void Camera::Inputs(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    //Basic Camera Controls
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        Position += speed * Orientation;
    }

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        Position += speed * -glm::normalize(glm::cross(Orientation, Up));

    }

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        Position += speed * -Orientation;
    }

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        Position += speed * glm::normalize(glm::cross(Orientation, Up));
    }

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_SPACE) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        Position += speed * Up;
    }

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_LEFT_CONTROL) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        Position += speed * -Up;
    }

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_LEFT_SHIFT) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        speed = 0.4f;
    }

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_LEFT_SHIFT) == GLFW_RELEASE)
    {
        speed = 0.1f;
    }

    //Mouse Control
    if (glfwGetMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT) == GLFW_PRESS) //Hide cursor when left mouse button is pressed
    {
        glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_HIDDEN);

        double MouseX;
        double MouseY;
        glfwGetCursorPos(window, &MouseX, &MouseY);

        float rotX = sensitivity * (float)(MouseY - (height / 2)) / height;
        float rotY = sensitivity * (float)(MouseX - (height / 2)) / height;

        glm::vec3 newOrientation = glm::rotate(Orientation, glm::radians(-rotX), glm::normalize(glm::cross(Orientation, Up)));

        if (!((glm::angle(newOrientation, Up) <= glm::radians(5.0f)) or (glm::angle(newOrientation, -Up) <= glm::radians(5.0f))))
        {
            Orientation = newOrientation;
        }

        Orientation = glm::rotate(Orientation, glm::radians(-rotY), Up);
        glfwSetCursorPos(window, (width / 2), (height / 2));
    }

    if (glfwGetMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT) == GLFW_RELEASE) //Show cursor when left mouse button is released
    {
        glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_NORMAL);
    }
}
```

### Shapes.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SHAPES_H
#define SHAPES_H

#include "Renderer.h"

#include <GL/glew.h>    
#include <glm.hpp>
#include <gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <gtx/rotate_vector.hpp>
#include <gtx/vector_angle.hpp>


inline void GeneralVao(GLuint &VAO, GLuint &VBO, GLuint &EBO, GLint* indices, GLfloat* vertices, GLsizeiptr sizeofidef, GLsizeiptr sizeofvdef)
{
    //bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer, and then configure vertex attributes(s).
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    //EBO
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeofidef, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeofvdef, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //Position Attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    //Colour Attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    //unbind
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

class Shape
{
protected:
    GLfloat* vertices = NULL;
    GLint* indices = NULL;
    virtual void constructVao() = 0;
    GLuint VAO = NULL, VBO = NULL, EBO = NULL;
    glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::vec4 colourTint = glm::vec4(1.0f);

public:
    GLuint getVAO()
    {
        return VAO;
    }

    glm::vec4 getColourTint()
    {
        return colourTint;
    }

    void setColourTint(glm::vec4 Colour)
    {
        colourTint = Colour;
    }

    //Addresses
    GLuint* getVAOAddress()
    {
        return &VAO;
    }

    GLuint* getVBOAddress()
    {
        return &VBO;
    }

    GLuint* getEBOAddress()
    {
        return &EBO;
    }
    //

    void setPosition(glm::mat4 Matrix)
    {
        ModelMatrix = Matrix;
    }

    void rotate(glm::f32 angle, glm::vec3 axis) //Rotates by an angle (floating point) and an axis (vector3)
    {
        ModelMatrix = glm::rotate(ModelMatrix, angle, axis);
    }

    void scale(glm::vec3 ScaleFactor3)
    {
        ModelMatrix = glm::scale(ModelMatrix, ScaleFactor3);
    }

    void move(glm::vec3 Vector)
    {
        ModelMatrix = glm::translate(ModelMatrix, Vector);
    }

    void clearMatrix()
    {
        ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    }

    virtual GLsizei getIndicesStride() = 0;

    glm::mat4 getPosition()
    {
        return ModelMatrix;
    }
    virtual ~Shape()
    {

    }
};

class Pyramid : public Shape
{
private:
    GLfloat vdef[30] = {
        //Position                  Colour
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   //Front Bottom Left | 0
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   //Front Bottom Right | 1
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   //Back Bottom Left | 2
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   //Back Bottom Right | 3
         0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f    //Top | 4
    };

    GLint idef[18] = {
        //Bottom
        0, 2, 3,
        3, 1, 0,

        //Front
        1, 4, 0 ,

        //Left
        0, 4, 2,

        //Right
        1, 4, 3,

        //Back
        3, 4, 2
    };
public:

    Pyramid(Renderer* renderer)
    {
        indices = idef;
        vertices = vdef;
        constructVao();
        renderer->push_Renderer(this);
    }

    void constructVao()
    {
        GeneralVao(VAO, VBO, EBO, idef, vdef, sizeof(idef), sizeof(vdef));
    }

    GLsizei getIndicesStride()
    {
        return sizeof(idef) / sizeof(GLint);
    }

    virtual ~Pyramid()
    {

    }
};

class Block : public Shape
{
private:
    GLfloat vdef[48] = {
        //Position                  Colour
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   //Front Bottom Left | 0
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   //Front Bottom Right | 1
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   //Back Bottom Left | 2
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   //Back Bottom Right | 3
        
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   //Front Top Left | 4
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   //Front Top Right | 5
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   //Back Top Left | 6
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   //Back Top Right | 7
    };

    GLint idef[36] = {
        //Bottom
        0, 1, 3,
        3, 2, 0,

        //Front
        1, 0, 4,
        4, 5, 1,

        //Left
        0, 2, 6,
        6, 4, 0,

        //Right
        1, 3, 7,
        7, 5, 1,

        //Top
        4, 5, 7,
        7, 6, 4,

        //Back
        2, 3, 5,
        5, 5, 2
    };

public:
    Block(Renderer* renderer)
    {
        indices = idef;
        vertices = vdef;
        setColourTint(glm::vec4(0.3, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0));
        constructVao();
        renderer->push_Renderer(this);
    }

    void constructVao()
    {
        GeneralVao(VAO, VBO, EBO, idef, vdef, (GLsizeiptr)sizeof(idef), (GLsizeiptr)sizeof(vdef));
    }

     GLsizei getIndicesStride()
     {
        return sizeof(idef) / sizeof(GLint);
     }

    virtual ~Block()
    {

    }

};
#endif
```

### Vertex.glsl

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 camMatrix;

out vec3 ourColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = camMatrix * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    ourColor = aColor;
}
```

### Fragment.glsl

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec3 ourColor;

uniform vec4 colourTint;

void main()
{
    FragColor.a = colourTint.a;
    FragColor.rgb = ((FragColor.rgb - colourTint.rgb) / FragColor.rgb) * 100;
}
```

Comment: Crunch that down to a single-file [mcve].  Feel free to use [this](https://github.com/genpfault/glfw-mcve-base/blob/master/src/main.cpp) as a base.

Comment: Likely you're looking in the wrong direction. What is `Orientation`? Try `new Camera(Window_X, Window_Y, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f));` (-2 instead of 2)

Comment: @Rabbid76 tried it, that isn't the issue, unfortunately. I'm trying to work on a mwe but it's difficult when it's hard to pinpoint the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.
Turns out it worked, just the cube was unexpectedly black along with the clearcolor.